# Google signing is signing in automatically, also right after log out. swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

After writing the log in with mail, i'm integrating social logins to my app and starting with Google signin. It now logs in automatically at app start, not if I press the Google login button. If I cancel it at pop up window it throws an `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`on the token line in AppDelegate`. Also logging out doesn't prevent to log in automatically again.
It was quite confusing following instruction from Firebase manual for Google login so I sure made some obvious mistake.

Here's the code so far:

AppDelegate:

```
// start google sign in methods
    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
        -> Bool {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                     sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                     annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        // ...
        print("User successfully signed in with Google",user)
        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else {



            return

        }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else {return}
        let credentials = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credentials) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to create user with Google account", error)
                return
            }

            print("Succesfully created new user in Firebase with Google account")
        }
        if let error = error {
            // ...
            print("User failed to sign in with Google", error)

            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                       accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

//        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
//        var mainVC = self.window?.visibleViewController as? MainNavigationController
//        mainVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") as? MainNavigationController
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
    }

    // end of google sign in
```

The Google signin should perform a segue to main menu but it doesn't.
Only at first sign in it gets to the desired vc.

Here's the Login class:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn



class LoginViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {
// outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var backGroundImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordTextField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipSegue", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setGoogleButton()
        setFacebookButton()

    }

    // dismiss keyboard on touch outside textfields
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for txt in self.view.subviews {
            if txt.isKind(of: UITextField.self) && txt.isFirstResponder {
                txt.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }

    private func setGoogleButton() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
    private func setFacebookButton() {

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

// Actions

    @IBAction func newUserRegisterButton(_ sender: Any) {

        if passwordTextField.text != confirmPasswordTextField.text{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!){ (user, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipSegue", sender: self)
                }
                else{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func mailLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {


        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil{
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipSegue", sender: self)
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func facebookLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    @IBAction func googleSignInButton(_ sender: GIDSignInButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipSegue", sender: self)

    }


    @IBAction func logoutButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func skipButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipSegue", sender: self)
    }

}
```

The sign out:

```
 @IBAction func logOutButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // firebase auth sign out
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }

        // GSI log out
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        print("User successfully logged out Firebase with Google account")


        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initial = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = initial




    }

    func signOutOverride() {
        do {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()


            try GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect() 
            // Set the view to the login screen after signing out
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initial = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = initial

//            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "SignIn", bundle: nil)
//            let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SignInVC") as! SignInViewController
//            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
//            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: \(signOutError)")
        }
    }
```

I read many posts about revoking the tokens and disconnect the user from the app, but couldn't implement those solutions as some are in obj-c and others in older swift syntax.
Anyone having same problem as me?
Thank as usual.

Comment: This is not your solution, but the way to find issue in your application and where your app actually crash. So you can find solution for same.

In your Xcode, select Show the breakpoint navigator, In that bottom left corner click on plus button and add `Swift Error Breakpoint...` & `Exception Breakpoint...` then run your app with breakpoint enables mode.

This will stop in debug mode at your app crash point.

Comment: yes breakpoints are just for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many tries and error,thanks to Google's sarcastically useful  documentation, I found out what the problem was. They suggest to put the sign in inside `viewDidLoad()' and that obviously get's called every time the VC gets instantiated. I so Moved into the Google sign in button and left the delegate only in`viewDidLoad()
It all now works as expected.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        setFacebookButton()

    }


@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
    @IBAction func googleSignInButton(_ sender: GIDSignInButton) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "skipSegue", sender: self)

    }
```